# Query was empty error in php

Tags: php, mysql

I keep on getting this error with this code :

```
$connect01 = mysql_connect($host01, $user01, $pass01);
mysql_select_db($db01);
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
if(isset($comment)){
    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES(NULL, '$name', '$comment')");
    if(mysql_query($query1)){
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        die ("Failed " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I do define everything I just don't know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: what error u getting?

Comment: if id is your primary key it cant be NULL

Comment: cannot set id with null if id is primary key

Comment: Just use echo your query so that you will come what values are passed in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES(NULL, '$name', '$comment')");
if($result){
```

Note the $result variable

Comment: how it is different from what OP is actually doing?

Comment: He is executing mysql_query twice, he doesn't really need this, ohh, and please start using mysqli_query instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$connect01 = mysql_connect($host01, $user01, $pass01);
mysql_select_db($db01);
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
    if(isset($comment)){
        $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES(NULL, '$name', '$comment')");
        if($query1){
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            die ("Failed " . mysql_error());
        }

    }
```

if id is auto increment field then exclude it from your query. like

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES('', '$name', '$comment')");
```

Comment: how it is different from what OP is actually doing?

Comment: he doing $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES(NULL, '$name', '$comment')");
        if(mysql_query($query1)){

Comment: ok so please explain clearly what u r doing in your answer while posting .removing my downvote also +1

Answer (score 0):

try this query.

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (`id`, `Username`, `comment`) VALUES('','".$name."', '".$comment."')");
```

Comment: For me now it saying No database selected

Comment: please check your connection string and database name.